# mysql create dynamic tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table dynamically and the only problem I am facing is that creating the columns dynamically. I mean like I won't have fixed number of columns so I tried representing it as a variable but when I run the code it gives me an error. The below is what I tried.

the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your...


$colArray = array();
foreach($ml as $df){
$colArray[] =  "`".$df."` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,<br/>";
}

$columns = implode("",$colArray);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$table_name}(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
{$columns}
date VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
            )";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 echo $db->error;
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Remove the `<br/>` in your sql. That's going to give you an error. If you want line breaks use "\r\n"

Comment: Most designs that require dynamic tables like this are doing things the wrong way. Dynamic information should be in the data, not the schema.

Comment: @michael If he echoes it in a web page, he won't see the extraneous HTML. In fact, it will look right because it will cause line breaks.

Comment: Also, you should be compiling your columns without a comma. When you implode, you use `implode(",",$colArray)`

Comment: @Barmar - you're right, I need to sleep

Comment: @Rasclatt you are right the prob was with the `<br/>` thanks it worked now.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I posted an answer...disregard. You already got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially what should work:

```
$colArray = array();
// Since you want these two columns in order
// assign here
$colArray[] =  "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT";
$colArray[] =  "username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL";

foreach($ml as $df) {
    $colArray[] =  "`".$df."` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL";
}

// Since you want column last, assign here
$colArray[] =  "date VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL";

$columns = implode(",\r\n",$colArray);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$table_name}(
{$columns},
PRIMARY KEY (id))";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 echo $db->error;
 $stmt->execute();
```